# sqlite database in docker volume not opening

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create an sqlite db on a volume within a docker container. When execution reaches `c = conn.cursor()` a receive the following error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

I wanted to re-use the connection process so built the following functions, which I think might be where the problem is:

```
def create_sqlite_conn(db):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
        return conn
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        logging.warning("WARNING: Error accessing DB: {}".format(db), e)
    finally:
        conn.close()

def create_db(db):
    conn = create_sqlite_conn(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ip_ver TEXT, date_time DATETIME)''')
    conn.commit()
```

This is called with:

```
create_db('/home/web/data/new_db.sql')
```

This code runs outside of the docker container, which is why I wonder whether this is alpine or docker related. My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk --no-cache add python3 build-base linux-headers python3-dev \
        && pip3 install virtualenv \
        && addgroup -g 500 web \
        && adduser -D -u 1000 -G web web

WORKDIR /home/web

ENV PYTHONPATH /home/web/myapp

USER web

RUN mkdir -p /home/web/env /home/web/myapp /home/web/data/

COPY myapp/__init__.py /home/web/myapp/
COPY myapp/myapp.py /home/web/myapp/
COPY setup.py /home/web/myapp/
COPY requirements.txt /home/web/myapp/
COPY README.txt /home/web/myapp/

RUN /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 /home/web/env \
        && source /home/web/env/bin/activate \
        && python -m pip install ./myapp/ \
        && python -m pip install -r ./myapp/requirements.txt

VOLUME ["./data"]

CMD ["/home/web/env/bin/myapp"]
```

Starting the docker container I have tried with and without the '--privileged' flag and still get the same error.

Thanks,

Comment: From the docs: "A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not." Why do you close the connection in a `finally` block? This is unrelated to `docker`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if it's completely unrelated. I don't know whether you actually succeed in making the connection because it just gets closed either way. I suspect it would throw `NameError` though if the connection was not successful because `conn` wouldn't exist.

Comment: It runs if I put it all in the same function so I think you're right, this isn't docker related, apologies. However, having the db in a separate function is helpful so I don't have to litter other functions with try/except blocks but any help resolving this approach would be great

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what issue this would solve. Either the function can return a connection or it returns `None` (or something) so you'd still have to check the function output every time you called it for a connection. Plus, if it failed once, it fails everywhere in the code because the database simply doesn't exist so it's likely you program can't function at all.

Comment: I think we'll have to rule some stuff out here because I don't understand what's going on. What happens if you remove the `finally` block?

Comment: I think you're right, the finally block is ineffective. Thanks for your help, I have decided to drop that function in favour of putting the conn next to all the places I need to make the db connectivity, I guess its not that much extra code. If you want to put an answer up to that effect I'd be happy to accept it. Cheers

Comment: did you do that test though? I'm genuinely curious as to what the issue is here so any answer I give can only address half of what you asked, which is why I deleted my original answer.

Comment: If I comment the finally statement and the conn.close(), the code runs as expected. I didn't think that finally block would run until after the c.execute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to `docker`. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement,
>   whether an exception has occurred or not.

This is easily testable, `b` will exist regardless:

```
try:
    a = int(2)
except:
    pass
finally:
    b = 3

print(b)
```

So it doesn't make sense to `close()` a connection in a `finally` block. I don't see any reason to close the connection at all in this function because it only tried to do one thing: open a connection. Either the connection is successful or it fails and therefore does not need closing (indeed, calling `close()` in the exception handler is likely to throw an error because the name `conn` will not exist).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but what I don't understand is why the conn doesn't appear to be successfully returned to the calling function?

Comment: @Adam the connection is returned, it is just returned in a closed state.